# How to Security > Privacy settings for a "Watch Me Do" QuickAction in Automator

Tags: automator, quickaction, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm using Mac OS X 11.0.1 Big Sur

I used Automator to create a "Watch me do" QuickAction.  I've saved it (is seems to save in ~/Library/Services by default), and exported it to iCloudDrive/Automator.  I can run this script to completion successfully from within Automator without any prompts, warnings or errors.

During export, I was prompted to add it to the Touch Bar, which I did.  I can see it on the TouchBar.  However, when I run my QuickAction from the TouchBar, I get a popup message indicating that it needs to be added to the Privacy tab:

> The action “Watch Me Do” encountered an error: “This application must be allowed to control this computer using accessibility features, using the Security & Privacy preferences located in System Preferences, before using 'Watch Me Do'”

There are two buttons on the popup: Show Workflow and OK

- Clicking on "Show Workflow" opens the Workflow in Automator, and does not solve the problem.
- Clicking on "OK" closes the popup, does not open the Security Settings, and does not solve the problem.

I can see that Automator is added to Security & Privacy > Accessibility AND ITS CHECKED.
I can see that Automator is added to Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access AND ITS CHECKED.
I can see nothing in the Security & Privacy > Automation pane.
I don't see my QuickAction anywhere, nor am I able to add it anywhere.

I need the procedure to add my QuickAction to the appropriate section to satisfy the security requirement please.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on Catalina. I had created a small application and workflow that uses Watch Me Do and it has been working just fine. As of today, it's no longer working and I know I installed an OS security update last night. I wonder if it has something to do with that update.

Answer (score 1):

Check the list of apps in the "Accessibility" area of Security and Privacy. At least one of the apps that are unchecked will need to be checked. This is because after giving you the pop up error message, MacOS adds the needed app(s) to the list of apps allowed to "control your computer". But you have to manually check mark it yourself, because it is only added to the list, but not checked. (Note: not all the apps in this list need to be checked, just the one's relevant to your workflow.)

It's a confusingly worded popup message. Note that we can't even create a "Watch Me Do" until after Automator is given "Accessibility". (This may be confirmed by unchecking Automator in Accessiblity, and then trying to record a "Watch Me Do".) So, even before we are able to record a "Watch Me Do", Automator has Accessibility. Which means, the pop up message you are seeing is not referring to Automator, but to another app.

For example, if your "Watch Me Do" included a click of the menu at the top your Mac's screen, then you would have to give the "Finder" app "Accessibility" too.

To expand the example, I created a "Quick Action" to "Launch Application", and then "Watch Me Do". During the recording of "Watch Me do" I clicked on "File" in the menu at the top of the Mac screen. This menu click was performed not while Finder was the selected app, but while the launched app was selected, so it did not say "Finder" in the upper left corner of my screen, but rather had the "App Name" in the upper left corner of my screen. I was **not** required to add Accessibility for the app that was launched, but I **was** required to add Accessibility for Finder. (Edit: I discovered if the app being launched is already launched before running the workflow, then this example required me to give the launched app Accessiblity. Go figure.) ​

Note: if you had created an "Application" instead of a "Quick Action" then you would also have to give the application you made with Automator to have "Accessibility."

Answer (score 1):

Put your TARGET app in the Security & Privacy > Accessibility section, like if you are gonna run that workflow in Chrome, then put Chrome in the Security & Privacy > Accessibility (simply drag the Chrome.app file into the window).

That works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Check if Automator is allowed to control Bluetooth (same menu Security&Privacy). Worked for me. I never seen this "Watch me do" warning after that.

Answer (score 0):

On macOs Ventura, the description from error dialog does not match the redesigned System Settings structure.

1. Open System Settings
2. Select Privacy & Security
3. Select Accessibility
4. Enable the toggle for the given Automator "app"

If it is already there and enabled, but the dialog is showing up, remove it, (-) button, and add it again (+) button.
Source: [user EthanDMatthews on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/wlfhii/mac_os_automator_watch_me_do_error_quick_action/jalkvpj/)

Answer (score -1):

I've found that making your changes in the Security & Privacy > Accessibility section, and keeping the lock unlocked when quitting, ensures that the workflow operates as desired.

Comment: that's an accident, not a design intent